# Entity Framework C# SaveChanges doesn't take effect immediately

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Why `DBContext.SaveChanges()` doesn't take effect immediately when using another `DbContext` on the same using statement?

As an example:

```
public void ChangeStatus(int id)
{
    using(DBContext context = new DBContext())
    {
        var car = context.Cars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
        car.status = 1;
        context.SaveChanges();
        UpdateAnotherStatus(id);
    }
}

public void UpdateAnotherStatus(int id)
{
    using(DBContext context = new DBContext())
    {
        var car = context.Cars.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
        car.status2 = 2;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just want to know why is this happening. I know that when I call UpdateAnotherStatus outside using statement, it will work but I need to know why

Comment: Please include results and show what you are expecting.

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "doesn't take effect immediately"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly; this should work.... but not for the fetched entity in the first context. Let me explain.

```
public void ChangeStatus(int id){
    using(DBContext firstContext = new DBContext()){
        var firstCar = firstContext .Cars.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id == id);
        firstCar .status = 1;
        context.SaveChanges();
        UpdateAnotherStatus(id);

        //at this point, the data set in the secondContext
        //did not update `firstCar` because they are completely seperate.
        //to overcome this eighter refetch (slow) or use the firstCar object or firstContext
        //to update status2
    }
}

public void UpdateAnotherStatus(int id){
    using(DBContext secondContext = new DBContext()){
        var secondCar = secondContext .Cars.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id == id);
        secondCar .status2 = 2;
        secondContext .SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Entity Framework has a change tracker to keep up with all the changes made in the fetched entities. This change tracker lives in the context. So different context has different change trackers, which are not (really) aware of each other.